# Single CrispyForm Tabs 2 Django Models

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, multi-model-forms

I am trying to create a web page that displays tabs at the top. Each tab relates to more than one model. I am using CrispyForms as follows:

```
class TestCrispyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_tag = False
    helper.layout = Layout(
        TabHolder(
            Tab(
                'Name',
                'firstname',
                'lastname'
             ),
            Tab(
                'Address',
                'address',
                'city',
                'state'
             ),
            Tab(
                'Miscellaneous',
                'sex',
                'age',
                'birthday',
                'email'
            ),
        )
    )

    class Meta:
         model = PtData

class TestCrispyForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_tag = False
    helper.layout = Layout(
        TabHolder(
            Tab(
                'Tab 3',
                InlineRadios('HypertensionHX')
            ),
            Tab(
                'Tab 4',
                'DNADX'
            ),
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PtHx
```

I would like to combine both forms and display the tabs across the top of the rendered page ... here is the html code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

{% crispy form %}
{% crispy form2 %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This works, but displays the forms in order and cannot for the life of me (know enough here to be dangerous ;)) figure this one out. Anyone?

Thank you in advance for your help/assistance in this matter.

-Bob-

Answer (score 2):

If you want put all tabs to one holder - simply create "TabHolder" markup manually (copy paste autogenereted one from browser) in your template and in your *forms.py* you can split your form to several helpers:

```
class CommonFormHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CommonFormHelper, self).__init__()
        self.disable_csrf = True
        self.form_tag = False


class TestCrispyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PtData

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper_name_info = CommonFormHelper()
        self.helper_name_info.layout = Layout(
            Tab(
                'Name',
                'firstname', 'lastname',
            ),
        )

        self.helper_location_info = CommonFormHelper()
        self.helper_location_info.layout = Layout(
            Tab(
                'Address',
                'address', 'city', 'state',
            ),
        )

        self.helper_personal_info = CommonFormHelper()
        self.helper_personal_info.layout = Layout(
            Tab(
                'Miscellaneous',
                'sex', 'age', 'birthday', 'email',
            ),
        )
        super(TestCrispyForm1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class TestCrispyForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PtHx

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper_some_info = CommonFormHelper()
        self.helper_some_info.layout = Layout(
            Tab(
                'Tab 3',
                InlineRadios('HypertensionHX'),
            ),
        )

        self.helper_some_other_info = CommonFormHelper()
        self.helper_some_other_info.layout = Layout(
            Tab(
                'Tab 4',
                'some_other_field_or_whatevere_you_want_here',
            ),
        )
        super(TestCrispyForm2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**template**:

```
{# ... #}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mainForm">{% csrf_token %}
     {# paste begin of TabHolder markup #}
         {# of course you can change ordering =) #}

         {% crispy form form.helper_name_info %}
         {% crispy form form.helper_location_info %}
         {% crispy form form.helper_personal_info %}
         {% crispy form2 form2.helper_some_info %}
         {% crispy form2 form2.helper_some_other_info %}
     {# paste end of TabHolder markup #}

     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```